# Solving one optimization problem with variable function parameters

Tags: optimization

Consider the following maximization problem with constraint:
$$
\begin{cases}
& \max f(x) + g(y)\\
& x f(x) + y g(y) = B
\end{cases}
$$

Functions $f(x)$, $g(y)$ and constant $B$ are defined.

I'm interested in getting general solution for this problem.

Stuck on solving it. Lagrange method didn't seem to help me.

Comment: What are the definitions of $x$ and $y$?

Comment: What do you mean by a general solution? Since $f$ and $g$ are not defined explicitly, at most you will be able to get an implicit solution using first order conditions. There may be no solution - you haven't made enough assumptions to guarantee one.

Comment: @unseen_rider x, y are variables. Say they can get any real value.

Comment: @smcc By general solution I thought of an equation on f, g, B, x, y. And all x,y that apply to this equation are solutions of this optimization problem.

Comment: There may be no solution. Currently we cannot even say there are any $x$ and $y$ that satisfy the constraint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Lagrangian for the problem is

$$L(x,y,\lambda)=f(x)+g(y)+\lambda[xf(x)+yg(y)-B]$$

Let us *assume* that there is a  solution of the optimization problem and that it is a critical point of the Lagrangian.

The critical point(s) satisfy:

$$L_x=f'(x)+\lambda[f(x)+xf'(x)]=0\tag{1}$$
$$L_y=g'(y)+\lambda[g(y)+yg'(y)]=0\tag{2}$$
$$L_\lambda=xf(x)+yg(y)-B=0\tag{3}$$

---

Suppose $\lambda=0$. There may be a critical point satisfying $f'(x)=g'(y)=0$ and $xf(x)+yg(y)=B$.

---

Suppose $\lambda\neq 0$. Then rearranging $(1)$ and $(2)$ and dividing the former by the latter, gives

$$\frac{f'(x)}{g'(y)}=\frac{f(x)+xf'(x)}{g(y)+yg'(y)}.$$

Solving for $y$:

$$y=x+\frac{f(x)}{f'(x)}-\frac{g(y)}{g'(y)}$$

Substitute into $(3)$ and solve to get:

$$x=\frac{Bf'(x)g'(y)+g(y)[f'(x)g(y)-f(x)g'(y)]}{[f(x)+g(y)] f'(x)g'(y)}$$

and

$$y=\frac{Bf'(x)g'(y)+f(x)[f(x)g'(y)-f'(x)g(y)]}{[f(x)+g(y)] f'(x)g'(y)}$$

which may be another critical point (assuming I did not divide by zero somewhere).